# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, syntax

Getting a syntax error with the following query:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Customer.customer_No, Customer.customer_Name,
                 Appointment.appointment_No,Appointment.appointment_Date, 
                 Appointment.start_Time, Appointment.end_Time 
          FROM Customer 
          INNER JOIN Vehicle 
               ON Customer.customer_No = Vehicle.customer_No   
          INNER JOIN Appointment 
               ON Vehicle.vehicle_Ref_No = Appointment.vehicle_Ref_No"
```

I've tried the same query in SQL Server Management Studio and it fetches the data I need. Not sure what the problem is, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code fragment - how the command is initialized and used?

Comment: Please post the error. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
strSQL =@"SELECT Customer.customer_No, Customer.customer_Name,
                 Appointment.appointment_No,Appointment.appointment_Date, 
                 Appointment.start_Time, Appointment.end_Time 
          FROM Customer 
          INNER JOIN Vehicle 
               ON Customer.customer_No = Vehicle.customer_No   
          INNER JOIN Appointment 
               ON Vehicle.vehicle_Ref_No = Appointment.vehicle_Ref_No"
```

@ will allow you to write multiple lines and use escape characters.